# SolrNet in C# example

Tags: c#, solrnet

I am trying to write a simple c# program to just connect to my Solr instance.  I have downloaded the SolrNet library and made reference to SolrNet.dll in my project.  I am following some of the examples online but have been getting the error "ServiceLocationProvider must be set" when the last line of my code is executed.  Following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using CommonServiceLocator;
using SolrNet;
using SolrNet.Attributes;
using SolrNet.Impl;
using SolrNet.Impl.DocumentPropertyVisitors;
using SolrNet.Impl.FacetQuerySerializers;
using SolrNet.Impl.FieldParsers;
using SolrNet.Impl.FieldSerializers;
using SolrNet.Impl.QuerySerializers;
using SolrNet.Impl.ResponseParsers;
using SolrNet.Mapping;
using SolrNet.Mapping.Validation;
using SolrNet.Mapping.Validation.Rules;
using SolrNet.Schema;
using SolrNet.Utils; 

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Post
    {
        [SolrField("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

  
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connection = new SolrConnection("http://localhost:8983/solr/test");

            Startup.Init<Post>(connection.ServerURL);

            var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Post>>();
 
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Thank You

Comment: have you tried removing "test" part from connection URL?

Comment: I tried removing the test from the address but still get the same exception error

Comment: Adding reference to CommonService.Locator to my project has resolved the issue